# WPF toolkit CheckListBox SelectedItemsOverride not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a check list box from the wpf toolkit 2. I cannot get all of the selected items. I read that I am supposed to use SelectedItemsOverride to get all of my selected items but it does not seem to work. I put a break point in the setter for TestClassSelected but it is never fired. Any Ideas?

```
<xctk:CheckListBox Name="MyCheckList"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding TestClassCollection}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                   SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding TestClassSelected}"  />
```

.

```
public IEnumerable<TestClass> TestClassCollection
{
    get { return _testClassCollection; }
    set
    {
        _testClassCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TestClassCollection");
    }
}

public List<TestClass> TestClassSelected
{
    get { return _testClassSelected; }
    set
    {
        _testClassSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TestClassSelected");
    }
}
```

.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public String DisplayName { 
         get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); } 
    }
}
```

This is my test data I have been using.

```
TestClassCollection = new List<TestClass>
{
    new TestClass {FirstName = "FIrstName", LastName = "LastName"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Brad", LastName = "Holder"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Ryans"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Ryan", LastName = "Thomas"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Lee", LastName = "Rod"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Amanda", LastName = "Gustaf"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Holems"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Doug", LastName = "Schnitzel"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Lisa", LastName = "Bull"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Fred", LastName = "Simpson"},
    new TestClass {FirstName = "Scott", LastName = "Rogers"}
};
```

Comment: I understand that its too late but I was in such situation and for me helped _testClassSelected = new IEnumerable<TestClass>()

Comment: OP - did you find a solution to this? I've tried every combination of suggestions in this thread to no avail.

Comment: I've seen various sources saying "fixed in v1.8" etc, but it's not working for me on 2.1

Comment: DLeh- I believe I fixed this issue. I ended up needing to use an event in the code behind so it was not a pure mvvm solution. I could dig up the class and send it to you if you like so you can have a look at what I did. Let me know, it might take me a couple days to get to it though. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

try add Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger at binding

```
<xctk:CheckListBox Name="MyCheckList"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding TestClassCollection}"
                   DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                   SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding TestClassSelected, 
                          Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**update:**
I'd checked example code from closed issue at [Extended WPF Toolkit CodePlex site](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/18709).
Try to change TestClassSelected property to ObservableCollection. (Still keep UpdateSourceTrigger described above in .xaml)

```
public ObservableCollection<TestClass> TestClassSelected
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I gave this a try with no luck. Even with the trigger it still does not run the setter for the bound property.

Comment: Still nothing, I was thinking it might be an error in binding, but there is nothing in the output window and the get is called on first start up so I know the binding is correct. I wonder if the control has some problems. I also tried to use the "SelectedItem" to get the last selected item but that does not work either.

Comment: And did you checked code from [this link to issue on CodePlex](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/18709) i'd pasted in update ?

Comment: I didn't try the code in the link. I will try it and see if it works. If it doesn't I might just create my own, I would not have thought a simple control like this would have bugs but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it by assigning the private field of the property

In your example

```
private ObservableCollection<TestClass> _testClassSelected=new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined previous answers/comments and what worked for me was to bind `SelectedItemsOverride` to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, include `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, and attach a method to the `ObservableCollection<T>`'s event `CollectionChanged`.

The XAML:

```xml
<xctk:CheckListBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Display"
    ValueMemberPath="Value" 
    SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
</xctk:CheckListBox>
```

Code in ViewModel:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Item> AllItems { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<Item> SelectedItems { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += SelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
}

private void SelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle collection changed event
}
```