# How to get list of checked items from WPF Toolkit's CheckComboBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpftoolkit

I cant get how to do such simple thing as getting list of all checked items from WPF Toolkit's `CheckComboBox`.

View:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RouteSheetRecordOperations, Mode=OneWay}"
                    SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

View model:

```
Public ReadOnly Property RouteSheetRecordOperations As New ObservableCollection(Of RouteSheetRecordOperation)
Property SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations As List(Of RouteSheetRecordOperation)
  Get
    Return _selectedRouteSheetRecordOperations
  End Get
  Set
    _selectedRouteSheetRecordOperations = Value
  End Set
End Property
```

The main problem is that in setter of `SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations` property, Value is ALWAYS Nothing (null).

Comment: Did you check out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798451/wpf-toolkit-checklistbox-selecteditemsoverride-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Mode=OneWayToSource` from the `Binding`:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RouteSheetRecordOperations, Mode=OneWay}"
                SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations}" />
```

Also note that the setter of the `SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations` property is not supposed to get hit when you select an item in the `CheckComboBox`. An item is supposed to be added to the source collection so you might as well remove the setter and you probably want to return an `ObservableCollection(Of RouteSheetRecordOperation)`.

Also note that the property must be `public`.

Try this along with the above XAML markup:

```
Private _selectedRouteSheetRecordOperations As New ObservableCollection(Of RouteSheetRecordOperation)
Public ReadOnly Property SelectedRouteSheetRecordOperations As ObservableCollection(Of RouteSheetRecordOperation)
Get
    Return _selectedRouteSheetRecordOperations
End Get
End Property
```